# Manipulate linux workspaces with scripts

Tags: linux, desktop, workspace, window-managers

I want to write a script(s) that lets me manipulate Linux workspaces on my computers. I'm looking for compatibility with EWMH/NetWM compatible X Window Managers. I currently use `wmctrl` to move existing editor windows to desired workspace(s) with a script.

Now I would like to be able to get a list of current workspaces, so I can compare to my desired workspaces and be able to move to, add, or delete workspaces as necessary -- and do it all with scripts and not GUI tools or keyboard commands.

I've tried various search terms, but the best I can seem to find apply to Mac OS and that is using an unmaintained program.

Comment: [unix.se] would be a better place to ask about the available commands. Once you learn what the commands are, it should be straightforward to use them in scripts.

Comment: But if you can't get the scripts working, you should come back here and post what you tried.

Comment: I will do that.